# space complexity string builder

Tags: java, string, complexity-theory, stringbuilder

In the example below, if I take in a `String s`, would the space complexity be O(n) or O(1)? and if I were to append only vowels, would it still be O(n)?

```
String s = "dfgdfgdfga";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0;i <s.length(); i++) {
    sb.append(s.charAt(i));
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: What's `n`? The length of the `String`? How could it ever to `O(1)`?

Comment: Because it's an iteration of an unsorted list of characters, i would think it's _O(n)_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Space complexity* boils down to: how much "memory" will you need to store things?

Your code intends to basically **copy** all contents of String `s` into StringBuilder `sb`. Again: copy all chars from `a` to `sb`.

Of course that boils down to *O(n)*, with `n` representing the fact that you need *more* memory when you copy *more* characters. If you start making selections, you still have *O(n)*.

*O(1)* means: **constant** requirements. Which is simply not possible (space wise) when talking about making a **copy**.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you append the `StringBuilder` it checks if the builder array is filled, if required copies the contents of original array to new array of increased size. So the space requirement increases linearly with the length of String. Hence the space complexity is `O(n)`.

It does not matter if the letters are vowels, because the String Builder stores characters and not references to characters.

Although you might be interested in creating an implementation of String Builder that stores references to Character objects, but then it is more expensive to store references than the chars and also `StringBuilder` is final.